# how to query gap data with sql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have this data in `mysql 5.7`

```sql
drop table if exists t_test;
create table t_test (
  dates date,
  num int
);
insert into t_test values('2022-02-01', 10), ('2022-02-10', 20);
```

How to get this data with sql? `date_add('2022-02-01', interval 30 day)` = `2023-03-03`

| dates | num |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | 10 |
| 2022-02-02 | 10 |
| ... | ... |
| 2022-02-09 | 10 |
| 2022-02-10 | 20 |
| 2022-02-11 | 20 |
| ... | ... |
| 2022-03-03 | 20 |

Comment: @user1191247 Thanks for reply, I can create a temp table, It's data like this `select n from ( select @row := @row + 1 as n from ( select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 ) t1, ( select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 ) t2 , (select @row:=0) r ) tmp`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a recursive CTE :

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
  SELECT num, dates
  FROM t_test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT num,  dates + INTERVAL 1 day
  FROM cte
  WHERE dates + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= '2022-03-03'
)
SELECT dates, max(num) as num
FROM cte
group by dates
order by num, dates
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/4FE-QBGA)

Comment: Thanks for reply. use Recursion CTE is indeed a good idea, but the current mysql version is 5.7, It's does not support CTE

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but you could use something like the following:

```sql
SELECT seq.dt AS `dates`, (SELECT num FROM t_test t WHERE t.dates <= seq.dt ORDER BY t.dates DESC LIMIT 1) AS `num`
FROM (
    -- generate date sequence from min_date to min_date + INTERVAL 39 DAY
    SELECT t1.min_dt + INTERVAL (seq2.n * 10) + seq1.n DAY AS dt
    FROM ( SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 ) seq1
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 ) seq2
    JOIN (SELECT MIN(dates) AS min_dt FROM t_test) t1
) seq
WHERE seq.dt <= '2022-03-03'
ORDER BY seq.dt ASC;
```

Or using a UDV (frowned upon by many, but hey... ):

```sql
SELECT dates, @prev := COALESCE(num, @prev) AS num
FROM (
    SELECT seq.dt AS `dates`, t.num AS num
    FROM (
        -- generate date sequence
        SELECT '2022-02-01' /* START DATE */ + INTERVAL (seq2.n * 10) + seq1.n DAY AS dt
        FROM ( SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 ) seq1
        CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 ) seq2
        HAVING dt <= '2022-03-03' /* END DATE */
    ) seq
    LEFT JOIN t_test t ON seq.dt = t.dates
    ORDER BY seq.dt ASC
) x
JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL) def;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UjRSLDmK)

Comment: It's really not pretty(T_T), but Thanks for the idea.